# After some time barcode scanner throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-vision, android-vision

I have a barcode scanner using the new android vision library that worked perfectly on my device and on several others. But suddenly it stops working and I see the following exception in the log:

```
No implementation found for com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcode[] com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcodeDetector.recognizeBufferNative(int, int, java.nio.ByteBuffer, com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeOptions) (tried Java_com_google_android_gms_vision_barcode_internal_NativeBarcodeDetector_recognizeBufferNative and Java_com_google_android_gms_vision_barcode_internal_NativeBarcodeDetector_recognizeBufferNative__IILjava_nio_ByteBuffer_2Lcom_google_android_gms_vision_barcode_internal_NativeOptions_2)
E/CameraSource: Exception thrown from receiver.
E/CameraSource: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcode[] com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcodeDetector.recognizeBufferNative(int, int, java.nio.ByteBuffer, com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeOptions) (tried Java_com_google_android_gms_vision_barcode_internal_NativeBarcodeDetector_recognizeBufferNative and Java_com_google_android_gms_vision_barcode_internal_NativeBarcodeDetector_recognizeBufferNative__IILjava_nio_ByteBuffer_2Lcom_google_android_gms_vision_barcode_internal_NativeOptions_2)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcodeDetector.recognizeBufferNative(Native Method)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcodeDetector.a(SourceFile:39)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.c.onTransact(SourceFile:61)
E/CameraSource:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzb$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector.detect(Unknown Source)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector.receiveFrame(Unknown Source)
E/CameraSource:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource$zzb.run(Unknown Source)
E/CameraSource:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The test `barcodeDetector.isOperational()` returns `true`.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  We are looking into it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: No workaround yet. But it seems that Google pushes updates, because on my moto g 2014 it starts working again.

Comment: Any news? I'm suddenly having this issue on a bunch of devices. Some device is still working, i.e. Moto E, others cannot scan the QR code, i.e. Nexus 5, Moto G, Samsung S*.

Comment: Same error for me, it stopped working suddenly although it was working before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to recompile your application against Google Play Services 8.1. This workaround will appear shortly at https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes.

Comment: When will the version 8.1 be released?

Comment: I didn't see anything related with this in your link

Comment: 8.1 was released today.

Comment: Yes.  Recompiling the app and distributing a new version of the app will cause a download of the new version of the barcode libraries.  This should fix the issue.  Note that this was a bug, but has since been corrected (it should not be an issue for the next version of Google Play Services).